# How to JOIN to a Function that requires a parameter from another joined table?

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, join

When I try something like the following:

```sql
SELECT    *

FROM      Abc
JOIN      Def ON Abc.Id = Def.Id
JOIN      Ghi ON Def.Id = Ghi.Id
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT Result = dbo.SomeBooleanFunction(Abc.Id)
          ) 
          Func ON Func.Result = 1
```

I get an error message of: *The multi-part identifier "Abc.Id" could not be bound*.

What is the appropriate way to join to the result of a function when it requires a parameter from the joins outside it?

Comment: I guess your code snippet is simplified because `Func.Result` will always be 1 or NULL. Is that intended?

Comment: Why do you need a join at all if it's just in the select list? Move it up as a new field on your select.

Comment: @SpectralGhost - Well I needed to also filter by the result equaling 1.

Comment: @usr - What my issue is, is that I have a function that returns 1 or 0 that I need to be in the select list, but to get it into the select list I need to join to it somehow and was thinking that's how I could do it.

Comment: @CodeMaverick See my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the join source cannot reference outer columns. I do not know the reason for this. Reformulate the query using `OUTER APPLY` which is just like a `LEFT JOIN` but it can reference outer columns.

```
OUTER APPLY (
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT Result = dbo.SomeBooleanFunction(Abc.Id)) x
 WHERE Result = 1
) Func
```

---

You said:

> I can't possibly keep wrapping for each function result that I have to filter by.

You could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTablesAndJoinsHere
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT
  Result1 = dbo.MyFunc1(...)
  , Result2 = dbo.MyFunc2(...)
  , Result3 = dbo.MyFunc3(...)
) funcResults
```

You can easily add additional function-generated columns this way and select and filter on them easily.

Comment: I've made another try. Does the pattern that I just added help you? Why or why not?

Comment: Will this method work when one of the functions returns a TABLE?  Would I still be able to access the TABLE columns from say Result1.Column1 outside the CROSS APPLY?

Comment: A table is not a scalar. I assume your function is an inline TVP that returns a table of one row. Use `CROSS APPLY dbo.MyTVP(...) AS x`.

Comment: Yea, my table is one row, two columns.  I needed a way to return a BIT and a summed TOTAL.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you actually want this.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
           , dbo.SomeBooleanFunction(Abc.Id) [Result]
    FROM      Abc
    JOIN      Def ON Abc.Id = Def.Id
    JOIN      Ghi ON Def.Id = Ghi.Id
)a
WHERE a.Result=1
```

OR

```
    SELECT *
    FROM      Abc
    JOIN      Def ON Abc.Id = Def.Id
    JOIN      Ghi ON Def.Id = Ghi.Id
    WHERE dbo.SomeBooleanFunction(Abc.Id)=1
```

Comment: The problem with that is that this is just a small example of a much larger query with many filters.  I can't possibly keep wrapping for each function result that I have to filter by.

Comment: @CodeMaverick What about the second option?

Comment: The second option doesn't allow me to use it in the select list.  But, actually ... at that point, they'd all be 1 so I could statically put it in the list.  I need to rethink something.